# Poblar ListView con Volley + php + mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

Necesito poblar el `listview`, no soy capaz de mostrar los datos en `ListView`.
Os paso el código, en este caso muestro los datos en un `TextView`.

```
public class BuscarPartidos extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private EditText edConsultaDeporte;
    private Button btnConsultaDeporte;
    private TextView tvCuadro;
    private ProgressDialog cargando;
    private Button ConsultaTodos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buscar_partidos);

        edConsultaDeporte = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edConsultaDeporte);
        btnConsultaDeporte = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConsultaDeporte);
        tvCuadro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCuadro);
        btnConsultaDeporte.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void consultaDeporte() {
        String deporte = edConsultaDeporte.getText().toString().trim();
        if (deporte.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor, introduce algún deporte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        cargando = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Cargando","Actualizando",false,false);
        String url = Consultas.DATA_URL_DEPORTE+edConsultaDeporte.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                cargando.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(BuscarPartidos.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }



    private void showJSON(String response){
        String deporte="";
        String nivel="";
        String numjug = "";
        String polideportivo = "";
        String fechapar = "";
        String horapar = "";

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Consultas.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            deporte = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_DEPORTE);
            nivel = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_NIVEL);
            numjug = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_NUMJUG);
            polideportivo = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_POLIDEPORTIVO);
            fechapar = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_FECHAPAR);
            horapar = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_HORAPAR);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tvCuadro.setText("Fecha: " + fechapar + "Hora: " + horapar);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        consultaDeporte();
    }
}
```

Esta es la otra clase que utilizo.

```
public class Consultas {

        //URL del fichero PHP de consulta para deporte
        public static final String DATA_URL_DEPORTE = "http://proyecto2gs.esy.es/consultaDeporte.php?deporte=";
        public static final String DATA_URL_consultaTodos = "http://proyecto2gs.esy.es/consultaTodos.php";
        //Tabla Partidos
        public static final String KEY_DEPORTE = "deporte";
        public static final String KEY_NIVEL = "nivel";
        public static final String KEY_NUMJUG = "numjug";
        public static final String KEY_POLIDEPORTIVO = "polideportivo";
        public static final String KEY_FECHAPAR = "fechapar";
        public static final String KEY_HORAPAR = "horapar";
        public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

Comment: Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas asignando valores a la consulta que traes, primero debes modificar tu clase Consultas debe quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
    public class Consultas {

    //URL del fichero PHP de consulta para deporte
    public static final String DATA_URL_DEPORTE = "http://proyecto2gs.esy.es/consultaDeporte.php?deporte=";
    public static final String DATA_URL_consultaTodos = "http://proyecto2gs.esy.es/consultaTodos.php";
    //Tabla Partidos
    public static final String KEY_DEPORTE = "";
    public static final String KEY_NIVEL = "";
    public static final String KEY_NUMJUG = "";
    public static final String KEY_POLIDEPORTIVO = "";
    public static final String KEY_FECHAPAR = "";
    public static final String KEY_HORAPAR = "";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result"; }
```

Luego, en tu consulta Json:

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        KEY_DEPORTE = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_DEPORTE);
        KEY_NIVEL = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_NIVEL);
        KEY_NUMJUG = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_NUMJUG);
        KEY_POLIDEPORTIVO = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_POLIDEPORTIVO);
        KEY_FECHAPART = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_FECHAPAR);
        KEY_HORAPART = collegeData.getString(Consultas.KEY_HORAPAR);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tvCuadro.setText("Fecha: " + KEY_FECHAPART + "Hora: " + KEY_HORAPART);
}
```

EN tu codigo usas el
JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Consultas.JSON_ARRAY);
que es para tratar arreglos json, mientras que segun veo tu quieres mostrar es un objeto.

De todas maneras si tienes dudas avisas por esta via y las aclaro en lo que pueda